# Visual Studio Online Access

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-devops

Visual Studio Online is available in Azure for creating Team Projects on cloud. Now what i have a doubt is if we can restrict the access of VSO from just corporate network or not? If yes how can we achieve that? Can anyone provide links or steps to configure it? Can Azure Active Directory help in this case?
For eg: There is XYZ Company that wants its developers to work with VSO only while they are on premise of the office. When they go home or outside corporate's network he/she must not be able to access or make changes in VSO.
Any help will be appreciated.!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it via using Azure Active Directory.

As we know that Azure AD can be integrated with an existing Windows Server Active Directory, giving organizations the ability to leverage their existing on-premises identity. Please check: 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/08/04/connecting-ad-and-azure-ad-only-4-clicks-with-azure-ad-connect.aspx

If the Visual Studio Online account is connected to an active directory, only users in that directory can get access to your account.

Please check the following two links for the details:

https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/setup/manage-organization-access-for-your-account-vs 
http://nakedalm.com/use-corporate-identities-existing-vso-accounts/

Comment: I am aware about that. What scenario i am talking is:
There is some XYZ Developer in the Company. He is registered with company's ID and have access to Azure and VSO as the the developers will be developing the code. So now if he go home and access VSO and download the code and leak it. So i want to restrict the use of VSO from corporate IP only or from corporate network only.

Comment: You can use your own enteprise sign on page which will allow you to log in only from your network.